# How to test Apple Audio Unit on Mac?

Tags: macos, core-audio

I downloaded and successfully (no error messages, at least) built the example PinkNoise Audio Unit from Apple's web site using Xcode 7.2 and OSX 10.11.2. It made a file called PinkNoise.component. How do I listen to the results?

The documentation says I should run the unit in AU Lab. I downloaded and ran AU Lab. I can't find any mention of what to do with .component files anywhere in the AU Lab documentation.

Searching the web I read that some people have tried copying the .component file to ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components or /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components. I tried both of those and restarted AU Lab each time. I searched through many menus attempting to find anything referring to pink noise but so far I have failed.

After reading some other comments on the web I tried doing a 32-bit build instead of a 64-bit build. That made no difference.

How should I be building and testing Audio Units?

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke with a representative of Apple, as I am having exactly the same problem. At the time, I was trying to test the pinknoise AU in garageband, so he was actually a head member of the garageband support team, and not a developer himself. After updating my OS (from 10.11 to 10.11.2) and garageband itself (to 10.1) garageband still did not acknowledge the AU plugin's existence. I have since then tried using AU lab to test the plugins and it also will not recognize them. However, I was able to get a completed (ie: not built on my machine) plugin to work on AU lab. The one I used was rms buddy from this link, which, as an effect, was selectable http://destroyfx.smartelectronix.com/extras/#rmsbuddy . However, even this plugin won't appear in garageband.

I should add that when I did the pink noise build (which I obtained from the audio unit examples page), I got a lot of deprecation warnings. I'm not sure if it was the same with you.

The guy from apple support basically suggested that the problem was with the code, and that I should call apple's developer support.

Hope that helps. I'll be continuing to work on this problem. Please let me know if you find any solutions yourself.